# how to make a Pure CSS Scroll to top

Tags: html, css

How to make a Pure CSS Scroll to top I tried doing it but I didn't know how to make it on click like in JavaScript  I tried doing it and this is my CSS Code

```
`body {
  height: 99999999999999999999999999999999999px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 95%;
  top: 92%;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}`
html code `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="study2.css" />
  </head>
<body>
  <span class="scroll"><button >Up</button></span>
<div>One</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: check this : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-only-back-to-top-button/

Answer (score 1):

You can use html!

Define an id in the body tag. ex:

```
<body id="exampleId">
```

Put an a tag on your page. and enter the href parameter using # the id you entered in the body tag.
ex:

```
<a href="#exampleId">Click Me And Go To The Top !</a>
```

You can design the optional a tag like a button!

Answer (score 0):

Scroll top with these to codes:

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```
<button>
  <a href="#">To top</a>
</button>
```